# Dockerfile: problem installing yarn / npm / npx / nvm in one RUN statement and using it in following one

Tags: ubuntu, npm, dockerfile, nvm, npx

I started learning how to create docker images from Dockerfiles recently and I already got quite far. But **I am facing problems using installed software from one RUN statement in following RUN or CMD statement.** See my simplyfied Dockerfile below:

```
# Working just fine
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash \
    && source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install 16.19.0 \
    && nvm alias default 16.19.0 \
    && nvm use default \
    && npm install --global yarn@1.22.19

# Problem using yarn / npm / npx / nvm in following RUN or CMD statemtens e.g.
RUN npm --version
```

The console shows me the error `npm: command not found`

The image gets built just fine without the last npm --version statement. And when I run the image and attach a bash to it I can execute the command by hand.

Also following other commands get not found:

```
RUN nvm --version
RUN npx --version
RUN yarn --version
```

**How can I persist the yarn / npm / npx / nvm installation across various RUN statements?**

Do I need to somehow add them to PATH explicitly? The $PATH contains following in an image without the last problematic statement: `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

I tried following commands, which did not help me out yet

```
ENV NODE_PATH ~/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      ~/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```